# How to change TextView color for a specific item in the RecyclerView adapter for songs when the next song is played?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to indicate what song is playable at the moment and change its TextView colour to blue. At the moment it works when I click the song, but when the current song finishes and MediaPlayer start the next song - I don't know how to indicate that to RecyclerView class.

I have a music adapter class that extends RecyclerView and I use static ArrayList variable musicFiles - declared and set in MainActivity:

```
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.musicapp.Activities.PlayerActivity;
import com.example.musicapp.R;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.InvalidPathException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static com.example.musicapp.Activities.MainActivity.musicFiles;
import static com.example.musicapp.Activities.PlayerActivity.mediaPlayer;

public class MusicAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MusicAdapter.MyViewHolder>
{
    private final Context mContext;
    private int row_index = -1;

    public MusicAdapter(Context mContext)
    {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.music_items, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    public static boolean isPathValid(String path)
    {
        try
        {
            Paths.get(path);
        }
        catch (InvalidPathException ex)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        String file_name_text = musicFiles.get(position).getTitle();
        String album_name_text = musicFiles.get(position).getAlbum();
        if (file_name_text.length() > 26)
            file_name_text = file_name_text.substring(0, 26) + "...";

        if (album_name_text.length() > 20)
            album_name_text = album_name_text.substring(0, 20) + "...";

        holder.file_name.setText(file_name_text);
        holder.album_name.setText(album_name_text);
        byte[] image = null;
        if (musicFiles.get(position).getPath() != null && isPathValid(musicFiles.get(position).getPath()))
            image = getAlbumArt(musicFiles.get(position).getPath());

        if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && mediaPlayer.getDuration() == Integer.parseInt(musicFiles.get(position).getDuration()))
        {
            row_index = position;
        }
        if (image != null)
        {
            Glide.with(mContext).asBitmap()
                    .load(image)
                    .into(holder.album_art);
        }
        else
        {
            Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(R.drawable.musicimage)
                    .into(holder.album_art);
        }
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v ->
        {
            row_index = position;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, PlayerActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("position", position);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        });
        if (row_index == position)
        {
            holder.file_name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008B8B"));
            holder.album_name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008B8B"));
        }
        else
        {
            holder.file_name.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext.getApplicationContext(), R.color.black));
            holder.album_name.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext.getApplicationContext(), R.color.black));
        }
        holder.menuMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v)
            {
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mContext, v);
                popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup, popupMenu.getMenu());
                popupMenu.show();
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item)
                    {
                        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.delete)
                            deleteFile(position, v);

                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    public void deleteFile(int position, View view)
    {
        Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                Long.parseLong(musicFiles.get(position).getId()));
        File file = new File(musicFiles.get(position).getPath());
        boolean deleted = file.delete(); // delete file
        if (deleted)
        {
            mContext.getContentResolver().delete(contentUri, null, null);
            musicFiles.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, musicFiles.size());
            Snackbar.make(view, "File deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // else is when the file is in the sd card
        else
            Snackbar.make(view, "Can't be deleted!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return musicFiles.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView file_name, album_name;
        ImageView album_art, menuMore;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            file_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.music_file_name);
            album_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.album_file_name);
            album_art = itemView.findViewById(R.id.music_img);
            menuMore =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.menuMore);
        }
    }

    private byte[] getAlbumArt(String uri)
    {
        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        retriever.setDataSource(uri);
        byte[] art = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
        retriever.release();
        return art;
    }
}
```

In that code - onBindViewHolder() method part changes the TextView of the clicked song:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v ->
{
    row_index = position;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, PlayerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("position", position);
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
});
if (row_index == position)
{
    holder.file_name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008B8B"));
    holder.album_name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008B8B"));
}
else
{
    holder.file_name.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext.getApplicationContext(), R.color.black));
    holder.album_name.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext.getApplicationContext(), R.color.black));
}
```

But then in my PlayerActivity class, I have buttons for the next song and the previous song and when I switch the song and return to MusicAdapter - I don't know how to change the TextView colour of the current song and return to the previous one.
Here is the PlayerActivity code:

```
package com.example.musicapp.Activities;

import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.musicapp.Musics.MusicFile;
import com.example.musicapp.R;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import static com.example.musicapp.Activities.MainActivity.musicFiles;
import static com.example.musicapp.Activities.MainActivity.repeatBoolean;
import static com.example.musicapp.Activities.MainActivity.shuffleBoolean;

public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener
{
    TextView song_name, artist_name, duration_played, duration_total;
    ImageView cover_art, nextBtn, prevBtn, backBtn, shuffleBtn, repeatBtn;
    FloatingActionButton playPauseBtn;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    int position = -1;
    ArrayList<MusicFile> listSongs = new ArrayList<>();
    static Uri uri;
    public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private Thread playThread, prevThread, nextThread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        initViews();
        getIntentMethod();
        song_name.setText(listSongs.get(position).getTitle());
        artist_name.setText(listSongs.get(position).getArtist());
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
            {
                if (mediaPlayer != null && fromUser)
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress * 1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
            {

            }
        });
        PlayerActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                if (mediaPlayer != null)
                {
                    int mCurrentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                    seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
                    duration_played.setText(formattedTime(mCurrentPosition));
                }
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(this, 10);
            }
        });
        shuffleBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (shuffleBoolean)
                {
                    shuffleBoolean = false;
                    shuffleBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_shuffle_off);
                }
                else
                {
                    shuffleBoolean = true;
                    shuffleBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_shuffle_on);
                }
            }
        });
        repeatBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (repeatBoolean)
                {
                    repeatBoolean = false;
                    repeatBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_repeat_off);
                }
                else
                {
                    repeatBoolean = true;
                    repeatBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_repeat_on);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        playThreadBtn();
        nextThreadBtn();
        prevThreadBtn();
        super.onResume();
    }

    private void prevThreadBtn()
    {
        prevThread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                super.run();
                prevBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> prevBtnClicked());
            }
        };
        prevThread.start();
    }

    private void prevBtnClicked()
    {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            if (shuffleBoolean && !repeatBoolean)
                position = getRandom(listSongs.size() - 1);
            else if (!shuffleBoolean && !repeatBoolean)
                position = ((position - 1) < 0 ? (listSongs.size() - 1) : (position - 1));
            // else position will be the same ...



            uri = Uri.parse(listSongs.get(position).getPath());
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri);
            metaData(uri);
            song_name.setText(listSongs.get(position).getTitle());
            artist_name.setText(listSongs.get(position).getArtist());
            seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000);
            PlayerActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    if (mediaPlayer != null)
                    {
                        int mCurrentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                        seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
                    }
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(this, 10);
                }
            });
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            playPauseBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
        else
        {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            if (shuffleBoolean && !repeatBoolean)
                position = getRandom(listSongs.size() - 1);
            else if (!shuffleBoolean && !repeatBoolean)
                position = ((position - 1) < 0 ? (listSongs.size() - 1) : (position - 1));
            // else position will be the same ...


            uri = Uri.parse(listSongs.get(position).getPath());
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri);
            metaData(uri);
            song_name.setText(listSongs.get(position).getTitle());
            artist_name.setText(listSongs.get(position).getArtist());
            seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000);
            PlayerActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    if (mediaPlayer != null)
                    {
                        int mCurrentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                        seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
                    }
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(this, 10);
                }
            });
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            playPauseBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow);
        }
    }

    private void nextThreadBtn()
    {
        nextThread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                super.run();
                nextBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> nextBtnClicked());
            }
        };
        nextThread.start();
    }

    private void nextBtnClicked()
    {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            if (shuffleBoolean && !repeatBoolean)
                position = getRandom(listSongs.size() - 1);
            else if (!shuffleBoolean && !repeatBoolean)
                position = ((position + 1) > (listSongs.size() - 1) ? 0 : (position + 1));
            // else position will be the same ...


            uri = Uri.parse(listSongs.get(position).getPath());
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri);
            metaData(uri);
            song_name.setText(listSongs.get(position).getTitle());
            artist_name.setText(listSongs.get(position).getArtist());
            seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000);
            PlayerActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    if (mediaPlayer != null)
                    {
                        int mCurrentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                        seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
                    }
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(this, 10);
                }
            });
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            playPauseBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
        else
        {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            if (shuffleBoolean && !repeatBoolean)
                position = getRandom(listSongs.size() - 1);
            else if (!shuffleBoolean && !repeatBoolean)
                position = ((position + 1) > (listSongs.size() - 1) ? 0 : (position + 1));
            // else position will be the same ...


            position = ((position + 1) > (listSongs.size() - 1) ? 0 : (position + 1));
            uri = Uri.parse(listSongs.get(position).getPath());
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri);
            metaData(uri);
            song_name.setText(listSongs.get(position).getTitle());
            artist_name.setText(listSongs.get(position).getArtist());
            seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000);
            PlayerActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    if (mediaPlayer != null)
                    {
                        int mCurrentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                        seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
                    }
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(this, 10);
                }
            });
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            playPauseBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow);
        }
    }

    private int getRandom(int num)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextInt(num + 1);
    }

    private void playThreadBtn()
    {
        playThread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                super.run();
                playPauseBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> playPauseBtnClicked());
            }
        };
        playThread.start();
    }

    private void playPauseBtnClicked()
    {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            playPauseBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow);
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000);
            PlayerActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    if (mediaPlayer != null)
                    {
                        int mCurrentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                        seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
                    }
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(this, 10);
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            playPauseBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000);
            PlayerActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    if (mediaPlayer != null)
                    {
                        int mCurrentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                        seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
                    }
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(this, 10);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static String formattedTime(int mCurrentPosition)
    {
        String totalOut;
        String totalNew;
        String seconds = String.valueOf(mCurrentPosition % 60);
        String minutes = String.valueOf(mCurrentPosition / 60);
        totalOut = minutes + ":" + seconds;
        totalNew = minutes + ":" + "0" + seconds;

        if (seconds.length() == 1)
            return totalNew;
        else
            return totalOut;
    }

    private void getIntentMethod()
    {
        position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", -1);
        listSongs = musicFiles;
        if (listSongs != null)
        {
            playPauseBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
            uri = Uri.parse(listSongs.get(position).getPath());
        }
        if (mediaPlayer != null)
        {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000);
        metaData(uri);
    }

    private void initViews()
    {
        song_name = findViewById(R.id.song_name);
        artist_name = findViewById(R.id.song_artist);
        duration_played = findViewById(R.id.durationPlayed);
        duration_total = findViewById(R.id.duration);
        cover_art = findViewById(R.id.cover_art);
        nextBtn = findViewById(R.id.id_next);
        prevBtn = findViewById(R.id.id_prev);
        backBtn = findViewById(R.id.back_btn);
        shuffleBtn = findViewById(R.id.id_shuffle);
        repeatBtn = findViewById(R.id.id_repeat);
        playPauseBtn = findViewById(R.id.play_pause);
        seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBard);
    }

    private void metaData(Uri uri)
    {
        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        retriever.setDataSource(uri.toString());
        int durationTotal = Integer.parseInt(listSongs.get(position).getDuration()) / 1000;
        duration_total.setText(formattedTime(durationTotal));
        byte[] art = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
        if (art != null)
        {
            Glide.with(this)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(art)
                    .into(cover_art);
        }
        else
        {
            Glide.with(this)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(R.drawable.musicimage)
                    .into(cover_art);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
        nextBtnClicked();
        if (mediaPlayer != null)
        {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        }
    }
}
```